# Inverse mapping in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mapping

Suppose I have an array A in Fortran of dimension 10 with numbers. 
However I'm only interested in a subset of those numbers (for example 3). 
I store those number in a smaller array B

```
B(1) = A(1)
B(2) = A(5)
B(3) = A(6)
```

I can also define a mapping table to store index 1, 5, 6 for example

```
MAP(1) = 1
MAP(2) = 5
MAP(3) = 6
```

How can I create an inverse map INVMAP such that

```
INVMAP(1) = 1
INVMAP(5) = 2 
INVMAP(6) = 3
```

with the constrain that INVMAP has dimension 3 (and not 10).

The point is that the array A is too big to be stored in memory and B 
is obtained iteratively (A is never really allocated).

Considerations:

- I do not care about the 7 discarded values but I care about the position of the one we keep.
- Since MAP and INVMAP are storing positions, there will never be collision (its a one to one correspondence).

Maybe it could be possible with HASH or Fortran table but I'm not really sure how because I'm mapping numbers, not keys. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot, 
Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution.  No Fortran on this machine so not entirely sure that I have the syntax absolutely correct.  Define a derived type like this:

```
type :: row
    integer :: a_index
    integer :: a_value ! I've assumed that your A array contains integers
                       ! use another type if you want to
end type
```

then

```
type(row), dimension(100) :: b   ! In practice you'll probably want b to be
                                 ! allocatable
```

and

```
b(1) = (1, a(1))  ! each row of b contains the value at an index into a and
                  ! the index
b(2) = (5, a(5))
b(3) = (6, a(6))
```

Now your `map` function is simply, in pseudo-code, `map(n) = b(n)%a_index`

and your inverse map is, again in pseudo-code, `invmap(n) = findloc(b%a_index, n)`.

Since the inverse map is a simple scan, it might become too time-consuming for your taste when `b` becomes large.  Then I might introduce an auxiliary index array pointing into `b` at intervals, or I might go crazy and start a binary search of `b%a_index`.

Answer (score 2):

> I can also define a mapping table to store index 1, 5, 6 for example
>
> ```
> MAP(1) = 1
> MAP(2) = 5
> MAP(3) = 6
> ```

I don't know if you know, but Fortran has a nice feature (one of my favorites) known as [Vector Subscripts](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-vector-subscripts). You can pass an 'array of indices' as an index to an array, and get the elements corresponding to each index, like this:

```
integer :: A(10) = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
integer :: map(3) = [1, 5, 6]
print *, A(map)
! outputs 10 50 60
```

> How can I create an inverse map INVMAP such that
>
> ```
> INVMAP(1) = 1
> INVMAP(5) = 2 
> INVMAP(6) = 3
> ```

Well, if your INVMAP will have a domain and an image of different sizes, it must be a function, not an array. I mean, INVMAP cannot be an array of length 3 and accept indices from 1 to 6, right? Arrays in Fortran (and in most languages) imply contiguous indices.

The intrinsic function `FINDLOC` can be pretty handy here (I am asuming your function is bijector).

```
function invmap(map, ids)
  integer :: ids(:), map(:), invmap(size(ids))
  invmap = [(findloc(map, i), i = 1, size(ids))]
end
```

You could use this function to relate each map value to its position on map

```
integer :: myinvmap = invmap(map, [6, 1, 5])
print *, myinvmap         ! outputs 3 1 2
print *, invmap(map, [5]) ! outputs 2
```

> The point is that the array A is too big to be stored in memory and B
>   is obtained iteratively (A is never really allocated).

Now, if you will never allocate the big array, then its values will also be accessed by some function (you can consider it a function actually). You have basically two options here:

1. Have two arrays, one with the values got from big_array_function, and one with the parameter you passed to big_array (the indices).
2. Have one array of pairs [index, value]. It is the answer that @HighPerformanceMark provided.

Comment: You are totally right, @francescalus. Thank you for the precise comment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively... (and not tested...)

```
Integer, dimension(100) :: A
Logical, dimension(100) :: A_Mask
Integer, dimension(  3) :: B
Integer, dimension(. 3) :: A_pos
Integer, dimension(. 3) :: I, J

A_Mask    = .false.
A_Mask(1) = .true.
A_Mask(1) = .true.
A_Mask(1) = .true.

B = PACK(A, MASK=A_Mask)

J = 0
Collect_Positions: Do I = 1, SIZE(A)
  If(.not. A_Mask(I)) CYCLE Collect_Positions
    J = J+1
    A_Pos(J) = I
ENDDO Collect_Positions
...
```

And then if one want to UNPACK, then the mask has the position... so it is possible to not worry about the position of A in general sense (but may be needed in the OP's case)

Comment: I suppose the repetition of `A_Mask(1) = .true.` is a mistake ?

Comment: Yeah 5 & 6 was I believe the OP's example. (LTR)